# Azure Kubernetes Service nodes cannot access internet

Tags: azure, azure-aks

Im trying to get web services to my existing service from aks managed cluster on azure. I did nsg port config stuff from portal to let outbound traffic go out and restarted vm several times. But my node cannot ping any ping on the internet. Im not trying to ping somewhere with its fqdn. Im trying it with its ip address.  How can i reach a service from internet into my cluster?

Answer (score 0):

How did you create the service and pod? Be default load balancer one  will create all the ruls for you and you dont need to create the rules by yourself.

You can share your pod details